# Why is the file name not being recognised whenever I run this program on Python?

Tags: python

```
def file_naming():
    """The users input defines the name of the file"""
    filename=input("Name your file: ") #user's input is set as the file name
    return filename #returns filename so it can be used later in the program

def naming(filename):
    """Taking the users input to put text in to the text file"""
    print("opening file{}",format(filename))
    finished=True
    with open(filename,'w')as f:
        while not finished:
            line=input("please input word(s), empyty to quit: ")
            if line !="":
                f.write(line+'\n')
            else:
                finished=True
def main():
    filename=file_naming()
    naming(filename)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()

def length():
    """Output the longest sentence from the user's input""" 
    maxlength=0
    infile=open("30075165.txt","r")
    for line in infile:
        linelength=lengthofline
        if linelength>maxlength:
            maxlength=linelength
            linelength=line
print maxlinetext
infile.close()
```

Comment: In function `naming` you have `while not finished` which resolves into `while False` (`not True`) meaning that your `while` loop effectively doesn't do anything.

Comment: According to the `print` statement this is Python 2.x. You should replace `input` with `raw_input`.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with your code: indentation in the length function, input should be "raw_input"(Asuming you are using Python 2.x. In Python 2.x `input` it isn't viewed as a string, `raw_input` is) and your while loop doesn't work.

Besides that, the length function doesn't get called and has a static file it opens (instead of your user input?). I made this dynamic.

```
def file_naming():
    """The users input defines the name of the file"""
    filename = raw_input("Name your file: ") #user's input is set as the file name
    return filename #returns filename so it can be used later in the program

def naming(filename):
    """Taking the users input to put text in to the text file"""
    print("opening file{}",format(filename))
    not_finished = True
    with open(filename,'w') as f:
        while not_finished:
            line = raw_input("please input word(s), empyty to quit: ")
            if line != "":
                f.write(line+'\n')
            else:
                not_finished = False

def length(filename):
    """Output the longest sentence from the user's input""" 
    maxlength = 0
    with open(filename,"r") as infile:
        for line in infile:
            linelength = len(line)
            if linelength > maxlength:
                maxlength = linelength
                maxlinetext = line
        print(maxlinetext)
        infile.close()

def main():
    filename = file_naming()
    naming(filename)
    length(filename)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot. Trying to implement a menu to allow the sentences to be analysed and saved/loaded to the file I have created for them

Comment: If this anwers/solves your question, You can mark it as 'answered'. That saves others the trouble to look at your question or helps others that have a similar problem.